# What's the point of Spring MVC's DelegatingFilterProxy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I see this in my Spring MVC app's `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

I'm trying to figure out why it's there and whether it's actually needed.

I found [this explanation in the Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) but it doesn't help me make sense of it:

It seems to suggest that this component is the "glue" between the servlets defined in `web.xml` and the components defined in the Spring `applicationContext.xml`.

> 7.1 DelegatingFilterProxy
>
> When using servlet filters, you obviously need to declare them in your `web.xml`, or they will be ignored by the servlet container. In Spring Security, the filter classes are also Spring beans defined in the application context and thus able to take advantage of Spring's rich dependency-injection facilities and lifecycle interfaces. Spring's `DelegatingFilterProxy` provides the link between `web.xml` and the application context.
>
> When using DelegatingFilterProxy, you will see something like this in the `web.xml` file:
>
> ```xml
> <filter>
>    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
>    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
>    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```
>
> Notice that the filter is actually a `DelegatingFilterProxy`, and not the class that will actually implement the logic of the filter. What `DelegatingFilterProxy` does is delegate the Filter's methods through to a bean which is obtained from the Spring application context. This enables the bean to benefit from the Spring web application context lifecycle support and configuration flexibility. The bean must implement `javax.servlet.Filter` and it must have the same name as that in the filter-name element. Read the [Javadoc for DelegatingFilterProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) for more information

So, if I take this out of my `web.xml`, what will happen? My servlets won't be able to communicate with the Spring container?**

Answer (score 132):

There's some kind of magic here, but at the end, everything is a deterministic program.

The **DelegatingFilterProxy** is a Filter as it was explained above, whose goal is "***delegating to a Spring-managed bean that implements the Filter interface***", that is, it finds a bean ("target bean" or "delegate") in your Spring application context and invokes it. How is it possible? Because this bean implements javax.servlet.Filter, its doFilter method is called.

Which bean is called? the DelegatingFilterProxy "Supports a "targetBeanName" [...], specifying the name of the target bean in the Spring application context."

As you saw in your web.xml that **the bean's name is "*springSecurityFilterChain*"**.

So, in the context of a web application, a Filter instantiates a bean called "springSecurityFilterChain" in your application context and then delegate to it via the doFilter() method.

Remember, your application context is defined with ALL THE APPLICATION-CONTEXT (XML) files. For instance: applicationContext.xml AND applicationContext-security.xml.

So try to **find a bean called "springSecurityFilterChain"** in the latter...

...and **probably you can't** (for instance if you followed a tutorial or if you configured the security using Roo)

Here is the magic: **there's a new element for configuring the security**, something like

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
```

as it is allowed by http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd, will do the trick.

When Spring loads the application context using XML files, if it finds a  element, it will try to set up the HTTP security, that is, a filter stack and protected URLs and to register the FilterChainProxy named "springSecurityFilterChain".

Alternatively, you can define the bean in the classic way, that is:

```
<beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
```

But it's less recommended, since you need to do a lot of configuration (all the filters that you're going to use. And there are more than a dozen of them)

Comment: "applicationContext-security.xml AND applicationContext-security.xml" is the same file name twice.

Comment: Thanks musiKk (I think you can edit the post directly)

Comment: This was the explanation that I was looking all along and cleared things up for me.

Comment: @jbbarquero: You're right but I wasn't sure what the correct version should be. I tend to leave that for the original author to fix so as  to not inadvertently change the meaning.

Comment: OK. In any case, I appreciate a lot your help to improve my response. Thanks again, musiKk

Comment: @jbbarquero if i have two beans implements Filter interface in applicationContext, and i want to execute in a order, then how can i make it?

Comment: @jbbarquero From your post I understand why we should implement DelegatingFilterProxy, can you suggest me any link where I can get its implementation.Thanks

Answer (score 84):

Do you know what a [Servlet Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is and how it works? It's a very useful piece of the Servlet Spec, allowing us to apply AOP-like concepts to servicing of HTTP requests. Many frameworks use Filter implementations for various things, and it's not uncommon to find custom implementations of them because they're very simple to write and useful. In a Spring app, most of the stuff that your app can do is in your Spring beans. A Filter instance, though, is controlled by the Servlet container. The container instantiates, initializes, and destroys it. The Servlet Spec doesn't require any kind of Spring integration, though, so you're left with a really useful concept (Filters) with no convenient way of tying it to your Spring app and the beans that do the work.

Enter the DelegatingFilterProxy. You write a Filter implementation and make it a Spring bean, but instead of adding your own Filter class to the web.xml, you use the DelegatingFilterProxy, and give it the bean name of your filter in the Spring context. (If you don't explicitly provide a name, it uses the "filter-name".) Then at runtime, the DelegatingFilterProxy handles the complexity of finding the real implementation - the one you wrote and configured in Spring - and routing requests to it. So at runtime, it's as if you had listed your filter in the web.xml, but you get the benefit of being able to wire it like any other Spring bean.

If you take that filter mapping out of your web.xml, everything will continue working, but none of your URLs will be secured. (That's assuming the name "springSecurityFilterChain" accurately describes what it does.) That's because this mapping is filtering every incoming request and handing it off to a security filter that's defined in your Spring context.

Comment: Thanks for posting this illuminating comment.  I am learning Spring Security now, trying to understand it enough to do customizations.  I had no idea what servlet filters were or what springs filters are. Your bit about AOP makes it clear WHY one would have filters instead of just using servlets........so you don't have to write the same pre/post processing over and over again in each servlet/resource

Comment: Wow. That explanation is exactly what I needed. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart if i have two beans implements Filter interface in applicationContext, and i want to execute in a order, then how can i make it?

Comment: @skaffman if i have two beans implements Filter interface in applicationContext, and i want to execute in a order, then how can i make it?

Answer (score 55):

## What are Servlet Filters?

[Servlet filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) are, in general, a Java WebApp concept. You can have servlet filters in any webapp, whether or not you use Spring framework in your application.

These filters can intercept requests before they reach the target servlet. You can implement common functionality, like authorization, in servlet filters. Once implemented, you can configure the filter in your web.xml to be applied to a specific servlet, specific request url patterns or all url patterns.

## Where servlet filters are used?

Modern web-apps can have dozens of such filters. Things like authorization, caching, ORM session management, and dependency injection are often implemented with the aid of servlet filter. All of these filters need to be registered in `web.xml`.

## Instantiating Servlet Filters - without Spring Framework

Your servlet container creates instances of Filters declared in `web.xml` and calls them at appropriate times (i.e., when servicing servlet requests). Now if you are like most of the Dependency Injection (DI) fans, you would likely say that creation of instances is what my DI framework (Spring) does better. Can't I get my servlet filters created with Spring so they are amenable to all DI goodness?

## `DelegatingFilterProxy`, so that Spring creates your filter instances

This is where `DelegatingFilterProxy` steps in. `DelegatingFilterProxy` is an impelmentation of the `javax.servlet.Filter` interface provided by Spring Framework. Once you configure `DelegatingFilterProxy` in web.xml, you can declare the actual **beans** that do the filtering in your spring configuration. This way, Spring creates the instances of beans that do the actual filtering, and you can use DI to configure these beans.

Note that you need only a single `DelegatingFilterProxy` declaration in `web.xml` but you can have several filtering `bean`s chained together in your application context.

Comment: very well explained.

Answer (score 19):

The thing is, servlet filters are managed by the servlet container, and not by spring. And you may need to inject some spring components into your filters.

So, if you need something like:

```
public class FooFilter {

    @Inject
    private FooService service;

    public void doFilter(....) { .. }

}
```

then you need the delegating filter proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about 'glue' stuff. As written in JavaDocs of [FilterChainProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.html):

> The FilterChainProxy is linked into the servlet container filter chain by adding a standard Spring DelegatingFilterProxy declaration in the application web.xml file.

Please see FIlterChainProxy section of blog [Behind the Spring Security Namespace](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/03/06/behind-the-spring-security-namespace/) for an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been perplexed by "springSecurityFilterChain" in web.xml and found this answer in springframework security document:

> The `<http>` element encapsulates the security configuration for the web layer of your application. >It creates a FilterChainProxy bean named "springSecurityFilterChain" which maintains the stack of >security filters which make up the web security configuration [19]. Some core filters are always >created and others will be added to the stack depending on the attributes child elements which are >present. The positions of the standard filters are fixed (see the filter order table in the >namespace introduction), removing a common source of errors with previous versions of the framework >when users had to configure the filter chain explicitly in theFilterChainProxy bean. You can, of >course, still do this if you need full control of the configuration.

Here is the link http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time but I had the same question and I found this: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/spring-security-behind-the-scenes.html

I tried to run my spring security project by removing the filter in question and also by adding it. What I found is if we add the filter, only then the call will redirect to required login page as defined in the spring-security configuration.

Hence, agreeing to @Ryan's answer.