# Is it ok to use a filter for counting page hits?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters, hitcounter

Do you think it is a good idea to use a servlet `Filter` to increment number of times a page is visited?

Something like this:

```java
@WebFilter("/posts/*")
public class PostHitCounterFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService; // somehow I autowire this

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {//...}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, filterChain chain) {
        String postUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().substring(7);
        postService.incrementVisits(postUrl);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {//...}
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a perfectly valid approach.


Note that the increment processing :

    `postService.incrementVisits(postUrl);`

should not be interleaved by multiple threads otherwise some increment could be missing.

Comment: To expand on davidxxx's comment, the counter should probably be an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html), to prevent multi-threading issues.

Comment: For how you can use spring to autowire the service see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6725234/217324

Comment: Thanks. I've set it up to be autowired in the init method:

`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, filterConfig.getServletContext());`

Comment: Whatever. The way I linked to has a lot less hassle writing a test for it.